# Refresh Datagrid when Datasource is updated

Tags: wpf, sql-server-2008, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a data grid that displays a Table which is bound to a `DataSource` which keeps changing on a time constraint. 
How to refresh the data grid's content when my`DataSource` values are updated.

P.S : The values in my `DataSource` Tables are updated by a monitoring system. Its table values are updated in regular intervals.

Where should I add my Observable Collection in my EF ?

```
    private IQueryable<MyTable> GetMyTablesQuery(TestDBEntities1 testDBEntities1 )
    {
         // definition of a Query to retrieve the info from my DB
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<EF_demo1.MyTable> myTablesQuery = testDBEntities1.MyTables;
         // Returns an ObjectQuery.
        return myTablesQuery ;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         // A New entity container is created that uses the object context
        var testDBEntities1 = new EF_demo1.HMDBEntities1();
         // Load data into MyTables. 
        var myTablesViewSource= ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("myTablesViewSource")));
         // the query which is defined above is executed here. It grabs all the information from the entity container
        IQueryable<EF_demo1.MyTable> myTablesQuery = this.GetMyTablesQuery(testDBEntities1 );
         //The query result is binded to the source of the myTablesViewSource, which inturn binds back to the list.
        myTablesViewSource.Source = myTablesQuery .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Either set the bound collection to an ObservableCollection and delete/add new values or use INotifyPropertyChange on the bound collection.

Comment: I have used connection string to connect to the DB and I am filling my datagrid.ItemSource to my dataset.I have not used ObservableCollection  to fill the Itemsource. so, now do I have to change the way of the data retrieval, eg: using EF ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to use an ObservableCollection:

```
BoundCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyEntityType>(entities);
```

Where `BoundCollection` is used in your binding. And then whenever the values are updated, you would clear the collection and re-add them:

```
BoundCollection.Clear();
foreach(var e in entities)
{
    BoundCollection.Add(e);
}
```

Here's another option that uses INotifyPropertyChanged and rebinds the collection each time. However, using an ObservableCollection is the preferred method as its is designed for adding and removing items which will automatically update the UI.

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public IList<MyEntity> BoundCollection {get; private set;}

  public MyModel()
  {
    UpdateBinding();
  }

  private void UpdateBinding()
  {
    // get entities
    BoundCollection = new List<MyEntity>(entities);
    // this notifies the bound grid that the binding has changed
    // and should refresh the data
    NotifyPropertyChanged("UpdateBinding");
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged( string propertyName = "")
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can use this ObservableCollection, when i bound to my database with Entity Framework right ? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this approach and let u know :)

Comment: I have added my EF databinding above. could you please tell where should I insert the ObservableCollection or INotifyPropertyChanged in-order to achieve the Data-binding via them? Thanks

Comment: Post the property you are using to bind to the grid, i.e., the property used as the `ItemsSource`. And what is `myTablesViewSource`?

Comment: "myTablesViewSource" is StaticResource which is used to bind in the XAML. I didn't use any property to bind to the datagrid. I have binded the datagrid to the datasource using Entity Framework

Comment: What is the type of `myTablesViewSource`? Is it a static class? If so, what is the type of `myTablesViewSource.Source`? i.e., List<MyTable>? Or?

Comment: Kindly look above, I have edited in comments, the result of the Object query is returned to the myTablesViewSource.source which in turns returns to a list.On the Xaml, "myTablesViewSource" will be used as the StaticResource for binding

Comment: You need to change the list to an ObservableCollection and then remove/add items as shown in the answer. Do not re-initialize the list each time, just clear and add the new items.